# Not all content of an array is written to a file

Tags: scala

In Scala, I have large array of type `Array[String]` called `lines` which I am trying to print to a file like this:

```
val pw = new PrintWriter(new File("gene_test.counts"))
pw.write(lines.mkString("\n"))
```

However, not all the content is written to the file. I have debugged the program and it looks like the last 100 or so lines are not printed.

Why is this happening and how can I make the entire array be printed?

Comment: Is this all your code? Can you produce a complete sample that shows this issue? (we can presumably generate a large amount of test data - how  big is `lines`?). Does it only happen with large arrays? And did you call `checkError` to see if anything had gone wrong? (for instance, are you out of disk space)

Comment: Have you tried with different files? Does that still happen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make sure everything is written you could `flush` the writer

```
val pw = new PrintWriter(new File("gene_test.counts"))
pw.write(lines.mkString("\n"))
pw.flush()
```

Another thing to keep in mind is to `close` the `file` and the `writer`.

A shorter solution could be

```
import scala.tools.nsc.io.File
File("fgene_test.counts").writeAll(lines mkString "\n")
```